# Bootstrap col order causing offset

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, col

I am new to Bootstrap and I'm having trouble with column ordering. In my first example, the page content is centered nicely (no push/pull).  In the second example, I have added the push/pull, but the page content is no long er centered.

[correct version](http://bootply.com/tippylorenz/92953)
[incorrect version](http://bootply.com/tippylorenz/92954)

Would love to learn why this is happening.  Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `col-md-4 col-md-push-8` and `col-md-8 col-md-pull-4`. Push force the column to the right. So does pull to the right.